# How to know the international prefix or country code of the contacts listed from ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I get the international dialing prefix (e.g. +39) or country code (e.g. IT) of the contacts listed from ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion? When a user enters in someone's phone number they do not include the country code.

I know of three ways, but don't think either one is a good option. Is there a correct way to do this?

(1) Can use NSLocal to get country code, but as stated on many stack overflow postings this is not always correct as someone could set their phone as Italian but be in the US.

(2) Check the kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey in the address book. But this isn't reliable as it requires someone to actually enter a persons address.

(3) Check the IP of the current country they are in and use that country code, but this isn't great as someone could be traveling abroad in the US, but their phone contacts are all Italian.

Thanks!